# Checking for Registry Key, then incrementing in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, registry

i'm trying to check if a reg key exist and then increment a reg key if it does.  I confirmed that i can set the registry value if i just put the value in directly. ie putting in the value 3.

```
$path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs"
$psv = Get-ItemProperty -path $path
$value = $psv."c:\windows\system32\test.dll"

if(!(Test-Path $value))
    {
    Set-ItemProperty -path $path -name $key -Type DWORD -value $value++
    }
Else
    {
    echo "error 1"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As administrator, Change `$dllToCheck` with your own value and try this :

```
$regPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs"
$dllToCheck = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\Shared\CaslVer.exe"

$exist =  get-itemproperty $regPath -name $dllToCheck -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
if ($exist -ne $null)
{
  $currentValue = $exist.$dllToCheck
  $nextValue = $currentValue + 1
  Set-ItemProperty $regPath -name $dllToCheck -Value $nextValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$value` is a number so `Test-Path $value` is always going to be false.  Which path do you want to check?  The file system path c:\windows\system32\test.dll or the registry key path?  If it is the registry key path, you know it exists because it you did a Get-ItemProperty on it.

Comment: I want to see if this key exist HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs\"c:\windows\system32\test.dll"  If it exist then increment the value by 1.  i'm pretty n00b at this... and looks like i'm using the wrong expression off the bat.  @Keith Hill

Comment: That is not a registry key.  The registry key is `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDLLs`.  `c:\windo‌​ws\system32\test.dll` is a value under that registry key.  Use `Get-ItemProperty` on the reg key path and value to determine whether that value exists or not.  If it returns null, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out... what you are saying makes sense.  I modified my script and confirmed it working!!!  in hindsight... it was a ID10T error... Thanks!